# UWP TreeViewItem as WrapPanel

Tags: uwp, treeview

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="Group" x:DataType="model:GroupedTemplates">
        <muxc:TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" >
            <muxc:TreeViewItem.Content>
                <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="Pictures:"/>
            <Run Text="{Binding CountOfPhotos}"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </muxc:TreeViewItem.Content>
        </muxc:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Template" x:DataType="model:Project">
        <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=Page, 
                                Path=DataContext.TemplateClickCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Content="{Binding PhotoArray,
                Converter={StaticResource FromArrToGridConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <helpers:GroupTemplateSelector
        x:Key="GroupTemplateSelector"
         ProjectTemplate="{StaticResource Template}"
         GroupTemplate="{StaticResource Group}"/>

 <muxc:TreeView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding TemplateCollection}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource GroupTemplateSelector}">
    </muxc:TreeView>
```

As result, I have TreeView which items just go down like a list
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ77A.png

But I need that my elements in every TreeViewItem be in WrapPanel in Horizontal orientation. Could you help me?

[What I need like an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5XLo.png)

Comment: Why do you want to put the items in horizontal orientation? If you put the items in horizontal orientation, some of them will be invisible because it is out of the range.

Comment: So I wanna use a wrap panel to wrap items

Comment: Check the source code of TreeView to customize it: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/main/dev/TreeView